# Passing reference to instance into another object when new object is part of original object?

Tags: java, oop, architecture

Could be there any flaw (from design perspective) when passing `this` instance of parent class into another object's constructor when new instance will be part of the original instance?

```
public class Order extends AbstractOrder {

  private final OrderExecutionStrategy executionStrategy;

  private Order() {
    this.executionStrategy = new OrderExecutionStrategy(this);
  }

  // the implementation omitted for brevity...

}
```

I need to access data from parent instance in `OrderExecutionStrategy` class.

```
public class OrderExecutionStrategy extends AbstractOrderExecutionStrategy  {

  public OrderExecutionStrategy(final Order order) {
    super(order);
  }

  @Override
  public Optional<OrderPortion> executePortion(final BigDecimal newPrice, final TradeOrders orders) {

    AssertUtils.notNull(orders, "orders");
    AssertUtils.isGtZero(newPrice, "newPrice");

    if (ComparisonUtils.equals(getOrder().getPrice(), newPrice)) {

      final BigDecimal reaminingAmount = this.getOrder().summary().getRemainToFill();

      if (ValidationUtils.isGtZero(reaminingAmount)) {
        return Optional.of(new OrderPortion(this.getOrder().getId(), reaminingAmount));
      }

    }

    return Optional.empty();

  }

}
```

Comment: It is hard to say.  There is insufficient detail.

Comment: @StephenC What kind of detail should I clarify? I am thinking that these two instances could negatively affect each other, an endless loop or something in that sense.

Comment: Well, maybe show us the parent class, the strategy class, and explain what the code is supposed to do.  *"I am thinking that these two instances could negatively affect each other, an endless loop or something in that sense."* - Obviously, we can't say if those things could happen without seeing the code.  OTOH, they could be implementation flaws (aka bugs) rather than design flaws.  (What do you mean by "design" in this context?)

Comment: @StephenC Added strategy class, by design I mean type of composition of these objects.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see any design flaws in this.

However, there are a couple of caveats:

1. I am talking about design flaws, not implementation flaws.

   > "I am thinking that these two instances could negatively affect each other, an endless loop or something in that sense."

   Those would be implementation flaws (aka bugs), not design flaws.  A lot more context is required to check for that kind of thing.
2. You have only shown us a tiny part of the design, with few clues as to how this fits into the "bigger picture".